# Converting Datatypes in c#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Here are my C# classes:

```
public class myClass {

     // Some properties irrelevant to the question

     public List<someObject> ListOfStuff { get; set; }
}


public class someObject {

   public string Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Question: is it possible to extract all `Id` into a separate array and all `Name` into another separate array?

For instance, something like this:

```
 myClass foo;
 // Populate foo...  
 List<string> names = foo.ListOfStuff( what goes here? );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method of LINQ:

```
List<string> names = foo.ListOfStuff.Select(x => x.Name).ToList<string>();
List<string> ids = foo.ListOfStuff.Select(x => x.Id).ToList<string>();
```

Comment: @Hasanain: Right, just added it.

Comment: Might want to add that you need to include `using System.Linq;` to use LINQ.

Comment: @norlando: Well, it is written in the tree on the left of the [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) of the method. If we had to write the required `using` on every SO answer, I just think that would pollute the answers.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ makes this quite easy:

```
var idArray = ListOfStuff.Select(item => item.Id).ToArray();
```

To get your array of Names, just change the property you're selecting in the Select() method.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the linq queries to accomplish what you're looking to do:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = foo.ListOfStuff.Select(f => f.Name);
IEnumerable<string> IDs = foo.ListOfStuff.Select(f => f.Id);
```

If you want to store them in a `List`, then just tack a `ToList()` onto the end of those queries:

```
List<string> IDs = foo.ListOfStuff.Select(f => f.Id).ToList();
List<string> Names = foo.ListOfStuff.Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: The "Id" property is a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to accomplish this, e.g.

```
List<string> names = foo.ListOfStuff.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```